# Send Request to SabreCommandLLSRQ which includes special characters

Tags: .net, sabre

I am trying to send Ticketing command-W‡FCA to Sabre Web service named "SabreCommandLLSRQ" but i am getting response saying format issue i.e. Format-0014.

When i am executing the same request using JMeter, the response is correct and desired. But in my c# application, it is giving error mentioned above.

Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it was an encoding issue. For the expected special character, i needed to change the default request encoding to UTF8. Thanks.